# NameError at /Signup/ name 'all_users' is not defined

Tags: python, django, frameworks

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from .models import signUp
from django .template import loader

def index(request):

    template = loader.get_template("Signup/signup.html")
    context = {
'all_users': all_users,
    }

    return HttpResponse(template.render(context, request))
```

Comment: **`NameError`** raised when a local or global name is not found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**all_users** should be a queryset of **User** objects that you want to pass in the context. 
Try this

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

all_users = User.objects.all()
```

Then pass it in the context

```
context = {
    'all_users': all_users,
}
```